# numpy - Given a number, find numbers that sum to it, with fuzzy weights

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a number that you want to represent a total -- let's say it's 123,456,789.

Now, suppose you want to generate some numbers that add up to that number, but with fuzzy weights.

For instance, suppose I want to generate three numbers.  The first should be around 60% of the total, but with some small level of variance.  The second should be 30% of the total, again with some variance.  And the third would end up being about 10%, depending on the other two.

I tried doing it this way:

```
percentages = [0.6, 0.3]
total = 123456789
still_need = total
values = []
for i in range(2):
    x = int(total * (percentages[i] + np.random.normal(scale=0.05)))
    values.append(x)
    still_need = still_need - x
values.append(still_need)
```

But that doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way to do it would be to draw from a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

```
total = 123456789
percentages = [0.6, 0.3, 0.1]
values = np.random.multinomial(total, percentages)
```

In this case, the multinomial distribution models rolling a 3-sided die 123456789 times, where the probability of each face turning up is [0.6, 0.3, 0.1]. Calling `multinomial()` is like running a single trial of this experiment. It returns 3 random integers that sum to 123456789. They represent the number of times that each face of the die turned up. If you want multiple draws, you can use the `size` parameter`.

Comment: Does `np.random.multinomial` call an underlying function 123,456,789 times under the hood?  I ran `%timeit` and it seems impossibly fast.

Comment: Almost certainly not. Although you could simulate rolling a die, fortunately there are much more efficient ways to generate multinomial random numbers. I don't know what NumPy uses. But, for example, see Devroye (1986) "Non-uniform random variate generation". He shows how to generate multinomial random numbers as a sequence of binomial random numbers (which are quick to generate). A single draw with this method takes O(d) time, for a d-sided die.